# Fitting a display to an ebike kit

Tags: electric-bike

I have an voilamart ebike kit, [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07Q7FJ8ZY/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q7FJ8ZY)
Is there an LCD display I can add to this kit, I've had my eye on this
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07LBZ6KFN/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=A18NQE175QQAZM&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LBZ6KFN)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably not.

There’s no standard communications protocol for motor controllers and displays. Each manufacturer has their own system.

Adding to this, you’ve listed a controller which could have come from any dozens of factories using any number of generic designs. It’s not even clear if your controller has display support — looking at the wiring harness on the listing  I don’t see a lead for a display controller:

[image: wiring harness]

But many times the listings are incorrect and you get something else in the box, so who knows?

Unless you can find someone who says it works or who has tried it, there’s no way of knowing. That said, many things on amazon have a 30 day return policy so you could be the first.